# How to remove brackets when adding data to Arrays

Tags: java, arrays, hashmap

I'm new in Java. I want some advice how to cut brackets when putting arrays of data to HashMap, which I'm parsing from Xml file.
This is a piece of my code ->>>

```
final List<String> ITEMS = new ArrayList<String>();
final List<String> URLS = new ArrayList<String>();
final HashMap urls = new HashMap();

   NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("Row");                        
   for (int z=0; z<nList.getLength(); z++) {
        Node nNode = nList.item(z);
        Element eElement = (Element) nNode; 

        NodeList a = eElement.getElementsByTagName("item");
        for (int i=0; i<a.getLength(); i++) {               
            ITEMS.clear();
            URLS.clear();
            urls.clear();
            String b = eElement.getElementsByTagName("item").item(i).getTextContent();
            String c = eElement.getElementsByTagName("url").item(i).getTextContent();
            ITEMS.add(b);
            URLS.add(c);

            urls.put(ITEMS, URLS);
            System.out.println(urls);                               
            }
        }
```

Now I've got key=value pairs.

The output of this are:

```
{[Select product]=[bla-bla-bla]}
{[Single Landmine Shirt]=[http://www.sample.com/landmine-single-shirt]}
{[Women's Silver & Black Bar]=[http://www.sample.com/womens-silver-and-black-bar]}
{[High Density Foam Rollers]=[http://www.sample.com/high-density-foam-rollers]}
{[Sling Shot Hogan Wraps]=[http://www.sample.com/sling-shot-hogan-wraps]}
{[Heavy Duty Multi Grip Bar MG-1 - Closeout]=[http://www.sample.com/heavy-duty-multi-grip-bar-mg-1]}
```

My goal is to print value (Url) by corresponding key (Product name).
The problem is: when further I'm trying to compare any key from HashMap with String items(Product names which I've got in d-down list) - I've got a mismatch.
I'm sure it's because of quadrate brackets - stored in HashMap.

Please advice how to remove brackets from my **urls HashMap** ?

I'd like to have this HashMap looking like this:

```
{Select product = bla-bla-bla}
{Single Landmine Shirt = http://www.sample.com/landmine-single-shirt}
{Women's Silver & Black Bar = http://www.sample.com/womens-silver-and-black-bar}
etc.
```

Will be happy with any advice.
Thank you

Comment: And you are using raw types because...? And just write your own `HashMap` parser. You aren't forced to use `toString()`...

Comment: To begin, give a type to your map and change variable names: url and URL are way too similar names

Comment: Either do the entire output formatting yourself or create and use a subclass of `ArrayList` which has its `toString()` method overwritten.

Comment: Wait; are you aware that your implementation is completely flawed? You add the _same objects_ to the map several times; your map will be messed up. Why don't you just create a `Map<String, String>` and `.put()` into it?

Comment: @Luigi Cortese, Thanks for culture of code writing. This is just training, nevermind :)

Comment: @fge. Thanks!, seems Map<String, String> is make sense here.
About messing up - Agree. I just bad in Xml Parsing :(
Will try to improve it further

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better format yourself

declare this:

```
final HashMap<String,String> urls_corrects = new HashMap<String,String>();
```

do this in your loop:

```
 urls_corrects.put(b,c);
```

Print like this:

```
for (String one_item:urls_corrects.keySet())
                System.out.println("{"+one_item+" = "+urls_corrects.get(one_item)+"}");
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply Replace
urls.put(ITEMS, URLS);
By
urls.put(a,b);

because you put key and value in map as List. so it will print [].